Convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n^{\alpha}$ subjected to $x_1\in(0,1),x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2}{\sqrt{n}}$.
Suppose $x_1\in(0,1),x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2}{\sqrt{n}}$, find the values of $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ for which the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n^{\alpha}$ is convergent.

The following is my solution, please help me to check if there is something which is not right. Any help and comments will welcome.
Other methods also welcome!
(PS: I also post this in AoPs $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Solution:
It is not difficult to prove that: $\{x_n\}$ is strictly decreasing and$$0<x_n<1,\quad \lim_{n\to\infty }x_n=0.$$
By $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2}{\sqrt{n}}$, we get
$$\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}=\frac1{x_n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}-x_n},$$then
$$\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{x_1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}-x_k}.$$So
$$\frac{1}{x_1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{x_1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}-x_k}
<\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{1-x_1}+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}-1}.
$$As we know
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\sim2\sqrt{n},\quad n\to\infty,$$we know that
$$x_n\sim\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}},\quad n\to\infty.$$


Note the limits: by Stolz's theorem,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=2
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}-1},$$this means that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}2\sqrt nx_{n+1}=1,$$Hence
$$x_n\sim\frac1{2\sqrt n},\quad n\to\infty.$$


So $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n^{\alpha}$ is convergent if and only if $\alpha>2$.
Here also another method for
$$x_n\sim\frac1{2\sqrt n},\quad n\to\infty,$$
but  we should know $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt nx_n$ exists first and the limit is positive, if someone can give the proof of the existence and $>0$.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt nx_n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{\frac1{\sqrt{n}}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n-x_{n+1}}{\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{x_n^2}{\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})x_n^2\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{n}(\sqrt nx_n)^2\\
&=2\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt nx_n)^2,
\end{align*}
this implies
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt nx_n=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Your solution looks good to me :)

@
Sangchul Lee Thank you for your kind comment!

Here is a small comment: It is not clear to me whether $x_n\to0$ is immediate from the recurrence relation alone (although this becomes evident as the solution progresses). However, it seems to me that this fact has never been used in your solution.

@ Sangchul Lee
yes, it is not very very easy for $x_n\to0$, but I hope I proved that. I will give that!

Good thing about your solution is that it works without knowing $x_n\to0$ in advance; all you need is the fact that $0<x_n<1$ for all $n$ in order for the intermediate steps to work. :)

@
Sangchul Lee I give another idea for the proof of $x_n\sim\frac1{2\sqrt n}$ , but still some further work, can you give me some adivice  for this method! Thanks a lot!

Thanks for @
Sangchul Lee's helpful comments, in the follwing I give the proof of
$$0<x_n<1,\quad \lim_{n\to\infty }x_n=0.$$
Proof: Note the following first:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2}{\sqrt{n}}=x_n\left(1-\frac{x_n}{\sqrt n}\right)\implies x_{n+1}\leq x_n.$$
Case one: $1-\frac{x_n}{\sqrt n}>0,\forall n\in\mathbb N$, otherwise $x_n\geq\sqrt n$
for some $n$, but $x_n\leq x_1<1$;
Case two: $x_n>0,\forall n\in\mathbb N$, otherwise $x_n\leq0$ for some $n$, this would imply $x_{n-1}\leq0,\cdots,x_1\leq0$, because
$$x_k=x_{k-1}\left(1-\frac{x_{k-1}}{\sqrt {k-1}}\right),\quad 2\leq k\leq n.$$
So we have $$x_{n+1}<x_n,\qquad 0<x_n<1.$$
Suppose $x_n\to a(=\inf_{n}x_n)$, if $a>0$, note that
$$x_1-x_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x_k^2}{\sqrt k}>\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a^2}{\sqrt k}\to\infty,$$ which is impossible! So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n=0.$$
Another method for $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt nx_n=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Note that $$\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-\frac1{x_n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}-x_n}
=\frac{\frac1{x_n}}{\frac{\sqrt n}{x_n}-1},$$
so$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n\left(\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-\frac1{x_n}\right)
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\sqrt n}{x_n}}{\frac{\sqrt n}{x_n}-1}=1.$$
Hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt nx_n}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{x_n}}{\sqrt n}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-\frac1{x_n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n)\left(\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-\frac1{x_n}\right)=2.$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt nx_n=\frac{1}{2}.$$
